# Why does `time` not work on `echo`?

Tags: time, echo, zsh

`time` seems to work generally on my system:

```
➜  ~ time touch tmp.txt
touch tmp.txt  0.00s user 0.00s system 54% cpu 0.007 total
```

Yet its output seems to get suppressed when I attempt to `time echo`.

```
➜  ~ time echo
```

And to thicken the plot: it seems to recover its ability to measure `echo`, provided I throw that `echo` into a pipeline:

```
➜  ~ time echo  | xxd     
00000000: f09f 8d94 0a                             .....
echo   0.00s user 0.00s system 38% cpu 0.002 total
xxd  0.00s user 0.00s system 88% cpu 0.003 total
```

What's going on? Is `echo` outputting to `time`'s favourite stream, replacing its report?

Bonus points for: is there some way (e.g. stream redirection) to make `time echo`  output the usual report?

---

**Edit:** Some commenters have pointed out that I am using `zsh`. I'd not noticed that at the time, but that explains a lot.

`bash` uses normal executables to do `time` and `echo`.

```
bash-3.2$ which echo
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/echo
bash-3.2$ which time
/usr/bin/time
```

(Looks like I am using a GNU version of `echo` rather than the presumably BSD one, `/bin/echo`, that comes with Mac OS X).

Whereas `zsh` provides something significantly more special:

```
➜  ~ which echo
echo: shell built-in command
➜  ~ which time
time: shell reserved word
```

Neither of these are normal executables. Very interesting!

Comment: it looks like you're using `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It works for me as expected using macos sierra bash 3 and OEL 6.7 bash 4.

Comment: Works fine in bash 3.2.52 as well so it's most likely not a bash question

Comment: If you are using `zsh` use the external `/usr/bin/time` command.

Comment: @alvits: using an external `time` command will not measure a pipeline, but a simple command.

Comment: Ah, sorry; good catch. I forgot that this computer still ran `zsh`, since I'd made a point of switching back to `bash` on my other computer (ironically I did that because of bizarre `echo` behaviour). I've updated the tags.

Comment: @RolandIllig - does `/usr/bin/time echo ok` involve a pipeline? Enlighten me please.

Comment: @alvits: No, but the original question includes a pipeline, so the OP might think that the external `time` might be an equivalent replacement for the built-in `time`.

Comment: @RolandIllig: thanks for clearing that up. Yes, I had not realised that `zsh` was providing a built-in that was qualitatively different to the usual `/usr/bin/time` executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to happen when you use the built-in `time` (which measures a complete pipeline) combined with another built-in command, like `echo`, `true`.

Curiously, I could not find any mention of this in the `zshall` man page.

To work around it, run this:

```
time command echo
```

The `command` *precommand modifier* invokes the external echo instead of the built-in one.